# Oracle automatically insert record in multirecord block

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

My table looks like this:

```
+-------------------+
|Name               |
+-------------------+
|Name1              |
|Name2              |
|Name3              |
|Name1Jr            |
|Name2Jr            |
|Name3Jr            |
+-------------------+
```

My multirow block looks like:

[image]

What I wanted to know is how can I insert a record that has the same name with Jr after I insert a name. For example, I inserted Name2, it will also insert Name2Jr into the multirow block. Like this:

[image]

I tried in post record trigger:

```
insert tbl.name into name
from table tbl
where tbl.name = name||'Jr.'
```

***Note:*** I need to get the value of the automatically inserted data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.

- create a database block
- set its "Navigation style" property to "Change record"
- create block-level `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger:

  ```
  if :system.trigger_record = 1 and :test.name is null then
     -- do nothing if it is the first record in a form
     null;
  else
     duplicate_record;
     if substr(:test.name, -2) = 'Jr' then
        -- you've duplicated a record which already has 'Jr' at the end - don't do it
        :test.name := null;
     else       
        -- concatenate 'Jr' to the duplicated record
        :test.name := :test.name || 'Jr';
     end if;      
  end if;
  ```
- run the form